# What should I do if what I want to major in isn't available in my country?

Tags: application, career-path, major

I really wanna study to become an occupational therapist but unfortunately, there seems to be no options out there. There are no colleges or universities in my home country with a course in the related field.

If you must know, I'm from Cambodia. A country where people rarely concern themselves with this field and even sometimes, never heard of it. I thought of trying to get an international scholarship and be able to pursue my dreams abroad.  However, it seems I have no luck and I'm afraid I have to settle for the cards I've been dealt with.

Comment: If you intend to stay in Cambodia, it seems like a poor career choice, given what you say. You might just need to explore options elsewhere with a move.

Comment: Note that the close votes are because undergraduate admissions is considered off topic here.

Comment: This may not be applicable to you, but I'd like to remind my colleagues that there are countries where many jobs are not taught at university, but instead are taught at professional schools, through formalized internships, etc. For example, in Germany you would not learn to be a physical therapist at a university. (I have no idea about the Cambodian education system, and so can't say where to look there.)

Comment: Thank you for writing a very precise and general question. Did you consider a remote university?some of them are highly reputable (for example the Open University in the UK).
You will have the issue of getting your deg recognized (formally or informally) in your country, this is something that will require working with local professionals in similar fields (I am sure the top 0.5% of Cambodia can be involved, you just need to get in touch with them through association/political-parties/etcetc)
https://www.wfot.org/member-organisations/apotrg-asia-pacific-occupational-therapy-regional-group

Comment: Most occupational therapists I’ve seen in Cambodia are foreigners so they definitely got their degrees in their country and chose to work here instead.

Answer (score 1):

Ask occupational therapists in Cambodia how they got into the profession. If they studied in other countries, they might be able to tell you how to get funding, if it's available. Otherwise if there's a way to become an occupational therapist by studying a related field, they might also be able to tell you what that way is.